# Accessing the camera by Actionsheet option

Tags: swift

I'm trying to give the user two options uploading an image, the first the the photo library, and the second is the camera. I have an Actionsheet where the user can choose which way he wants to upload an image, but when clicking on the camera option, the camera app won't open. I did add the Privacy needed in the plist file.
This is my actionsheet code:

```
extension MoreReportsVC: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

func handleAddPhoto() {
    showSimpleActionSheet(controller: self)
}


func showSimpleActionSheet(controller: UIViewController) {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Add a photo", message: "Please Select an option", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "From photo library", style: .default, handler: { (_) in
        self.imagePicker.getImage(fromSourceType: .photoLibrary)
    }))

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Open camera app", style: .default, handler: { (_) in
        self.imagePicker.getImage(fromSourceType: .camera)
    }))

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: .cancel, handler: { (_) in
        print("User click Dismiss button")
    }))

    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: {
        print("completion block")
    })
}
}
```

This is my ImagePicker code:

```
class ImagePickerManager: UIViewController, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {

var placeholderImage: UIImageView?
func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
    //TODO:
}

func getImage(fromSourceType sourceType: UIImagePickerController.SourceType){
    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(sourceType){
        let imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePickerController.delegate = self
        imagePickerController.sourceType = sourceType
        self.present(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
}
```

The imagePicker in the actionsheet, is just a ImagePickerManager variable.
The app won't crash or anything, and it is getting to the getImage method, but just don't open the camera.

EDIT: I think the problem is in the delegate = self. self needs to be the VC I try to view the imagepicker from if im not wrong. and currently it is ImagePickerManager but I can't find a way to set it as my VC.

Comment: Simulator/device ?

Comment: If you know it's getting to `getImage`, then why do you not _debug?_ Put a breakpoint on the `if` statement and _walk through the function_ one line at a time and see what's going wrong. For example, perhaps the `if` is failing and so we never enter the curly braces.

Comment: @Sh_Khan device. it gets to the if, but won't even show the premission alert.

Comment: @matt Thanks, I did try, and everything looks ok, it even gets to the present line, but still nothing show up.

Comment: Are there any warning / errors appearing in the Console?

Comment: @matt no error, I think the error is in the delegate line. I wrote the same method in the VC I want it and it works perfectly.

Comment: OK but if MoreReportsVC is able to present the alert in the first place, then it is MoreReportsVC that needs to present the image picker controller, it seems to me. I've given an answer suggesting this. I don't understand what ImagePickerManager is doing in the story, i.e. why it is a UIViewController.

Comment: @matt I tried to make it a separate class so I can use it in few different view controllers. Clearly I did that wrong.

Comment: Yes, that's fine, but I'm saying it cannot _itself_ be a view controller.

Answer (score 0):

Add `getImage` method in `UIViewController` extension like this.

```
extenstion UIViewController { 
    func getImage(fromSourceType sourceType: UIImagePickerController.SourceType){
        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(sourceType){
            let imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
            imagePickerController.delegate = self
            imagePickerController.sourceType = sourceType
            self.present(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
         } else {
            print("Source type isn't available")
         }
    }
}
```

And call this method from `showSimpleActionSheet` method from `self`

```
func showSimpleActionSheet(controller: UIViewController) {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Add a photo", message: "Please Select an option", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "From photo library", style: .default, handler: { (_) in
        self.getImage(fromSourceType: .photoLibrary)
    }))

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Open camera app", style: .default, handler: { (_) in
        self.getImage(fromSourceType: .camera)
    }))

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: .cancel, handler: { (_) in
        print("User click Dismiss button")
    }))

    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: {
        print("completion block")
    })
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I ran the app on my iPhone now, it is getting to the if statment and not the else, but the camera won't open, I also don't get the alert asking for premission.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `ImagePickerManager` isn't actually a reference to any view controller currently in the interface. Thus, `self.present` does nothing because `self` is not the current view controller.

If you want to put image picker management into an encapsulated class that is not the current view controller, the encapsulation should not *itself* be a view controller; it should just be an ordinary object. You then won't be able to say `self.present`, so you will need to provide this object with a reference to the current view controller, which is in this case your MoreReportsVC.

Comment: Can you please give me an example? I’m new to this, for now I just put getImage in the MoreReportsvc and it is working. But I will need to use this method in more places and don’t want to repeat the block of code again.

Answer (score -1):

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "select image", message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
    let cameraBtn = UIAlertAction(title: "camera", style: .default){ (_) in
        self.showImagePicker(selectedSource: .camera)
}
    let libBtn = UIAlertAction(title: "library", style: .default){ (_) in
        self.showImagePicker(selectedSource: .photoLibrary)
    }
    let cancelBtn = UIAlertAction(title: "cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
    alert.addAction(cameraBtn)
    alert.addAction(libBtn)
    alert.addAction(cancelBtn)
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
func showImagePicker(selectedSource: UIImagePickerController.SourceType){
    guard UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(selectedSource)
        else{
            print("selected source")
            return
    }
    let imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
    imagePickerController.sourceType = .photoLibrary
    imagePickerController.delegate = self
    present(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey: Any]) {
    img.image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).